# How to get a smooth, uniform ParametricPlot of a 2D Region?

Tags: plotting, regions

This is an offspring of [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/206994/how-to-plot-a-complicated-region) question.

---

How to get a nice, smooth, uniform plot of the following? I.e. with no horizontal lines, and no ragged boundary at the top. I went with `PlotPoints` up to `400` and I'm dissapointed. What I'm actually after is a nicely `Export`ed .pdf.

```
ParametricPlot[{{1 + a1/(-1 + a2), 
    1 - 2 ArcCsc[2/Sqrt[1 + a1 - a2]]/π}, 
   a2 >= -1 && 1 + a1 >= a2 && a1 + a2 <= 1}, {a1, -2, 2}, {a2, -1, 
   1}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 1}}, 
  AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, PlotPoints -> 150] // Quiet
```

[image]

Comment: `ParametricPlot` doesn't allow constraint to be passed in that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid the artifacts from singularities and jumps, we can take a somewhat manual approach.

Notice that the bottom boundary is formed from `a2 == -1`, the top boundary is a horizontal line formed as `a2 -> 1` from the left, and the left boundary is a vertical line formed as `a2` sweeps from `-1` to `1`.

So we can get a clean graphic by plotting the bottom boundary by fixing `a2 == -1`, extracting the points, and adding the upper left corner to form a polygon.

```
bdplot = With[{a2 = -1},
  ParametricPlot[{1 + a1/(-1 + a2), 1 - 2 ArcCsc[2/Sqrt[1 + a1 - a2]]/π}, {a1, -2, 2}, 
    Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 1}}, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio] // Quiet
]
```

[image]

```
pts = Append[MeshCoordinates[DiscretizeGraphics[bdplot]], {0, 1}];

poly = Polygon[FindShortestTour[pts][[2, 1 ;; -2]]];

Graphics[GraphicsComplex[pts, {EdgeForm[], Hue[0.6, 0.3, 0.95], poly}], Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

[image]

---

Now notice that your constraint is not needed:

```
Reduce[a2 >= -1 && 1 + a1 >= a2 && a1 + a2 <= 1, a1]
```

> ```
> (-1 <= a2 < 1 && -1 + a2 <= a1 <= 1 - a2) || (a2 == 1 && a1 == 0)
> ```

We see the constraint says `a1` should range from `-1 + a2` to `1 - a2` instead of `-2` to `2`. If we plot for many fixed values of `a2`, we see we'd have the same plot if *all* `a2` were sampled:

```
Show@Table[
  ParametricPlot[{1 + a1/(-1 + a2), 1 - 2 ArcCsc[2/Sqrt[1 + a1 - a2]]/π}, {a1, -1 + a2, 1 - a2}, 
    Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 1}}, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, PlotPoints -> 100] // Quiet,
  {a2, Range[-1, 1, .01] /. {-1. -> -0.999, 1. -> 0.999}}
]
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly the approach I've just undertaken :o Although I've made a few tweaks. Will post in a moment.

Comment: The lower boundray isn't th problem I think. The upper boundary, especially the point `a1==2&&a2==1` has to be examined in more detail.

Answer (score 2):

As discussed by [Chip Hurst](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/207016/22013), the lower boundary of the region can be obtained by setting `a2=-1`. Therefore, this boundary is parametrized by `a1` only (let it be called $(A,T)$):

```
reg = With[{a2 = -1}, {1 + a1/(-1 + a2), 1 - 2 ArcCsc[2/Sqrt[1 + a1 - a2]]/\[Pi]}]
```

> {1 - a1/2, 1 - (2 ArcCsc[2/Sqrt[2 + a1]])/[Pi]}

This can be solved to get `a1` as a function of `A`:

```
sol = Solve[A == reg[[1]], a1][[1]]
```

> {a1 -> -2 (-1 + A)}

and inserted into `T` to obtain a function $T(A)$, Then the plotting is done with `Filling`:

```
Plot[reg[[2]] /. sol, {A, 0, 2}, Frame -> True, Filling -> Top, PlotStyle -> None]
```

[image]

The region can then be describe with e.g. `ImplicitRegion`.

Answer (score 1):

Try option `RegionFunction` inside `ParametricPlot` together with the Option `MaxRecursions`.

The second plot argument `1 - 2 ArcCsc[2/Sqrt[1 + a1 - a2]]/\[Pi]` is only defined for `1 + a1 >= a2`, that's why I only consider this restriction!

```
ParametricPlot[ {1 + a1/(-1 + a2) ,1 - 2 ArcCsc[2/Sqrt[1 + a1 - a2]]/\[Pi] }, {a1, -2, 2}, {a2, -1, 1},Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{0, 2 }, {0, 1}} ,AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, Evaluated -> True, MaxRecursion -> 4,PlotPoints->50, FrameLabel -> {a1, a2},RegionFunction -> Function[{x,y,a1, a2},   -a1 + a2 <= 1  ]]
```

[image]

Comment: With `{a1, -2, 2}, {a2, -1, 1}` and `PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 1}}`, the proper ranges I'm interested in, this plots a different Region than appears in my OP. And fyi, it's not `(a1,a2)` on the axes, but some functions of them.

Comment: The scaling of the plotrange shouldn't be a problem I think. I modified my answer!

Comment: I think your `RegionFunction` arg spec should be `Function[{x, y, a1, a2}, ...]`.

Comment: @ChipHurst Thanks, I changed  my answer!